# THREE.js Geometry - Disappearing side

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to make a 3D L-shape using Geometry.

I push the vertices and the faces for the top L, then for the bottom L, and finally push the faces for the sides using the already pushed vertices.

If I plot just the top L and the bottom L, they both show up.
But if I add the sides, the bottom L disappears.

Answer (score 0):

THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide})

Needed that side part.